# Was bedeutet die Redewendung "jemandem noch aus den Ohren raus hängen"?

Tags: meaning, idiom

Ich lerne Deutsch, aber es ist nicht meine Muttersprache. Einmal schrieb mir jemand:

> Es wird dir noch aus den Ohren raus hängen.

Ich möchte gerne wissen, was das bedeutet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr:** "jemandem aus den Ohren raushängen" bedeutet, von etwas zu viel bekommen zu haben.

---

*(Belege für die hier genannten Erklärungen sind unten aufgeführt.)*

Das *noch* gehört eher zum *wird* und unterstreicht den Verweis auf die Zukunft.

Somit ist die Redewendung:

> jemandem aus den Ohren raushängen

Ich kenne das eigentlich nur als

> jemanden zu den Ohren raushängen

aber möglicherweise gibt es da regionale Unterschiede. [Andernorts](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemandem%20aus%20den%20Ohren%20herauskommen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte[]=rart_ou) wird beispielsweise auch *aus den Ohren herauskommen* genannt.

Die Bedeutung lässt sich jedenfalls recht schlüssig aufzeigen: Wenn du **so viel** von etwas konsumierst (Nahrung, Information, ...), dass dein Körper **komplett damit "gefüllt"** ist (wie ein Behälter, den man von unten nach oben mit Wasser füllt), kannst du dir vorstellen, dass man gegen Ende auf Höhe der Ohren angekommen ist. Zu jenem Zeitpunkt hängt dir das, worum es geht, zu den Ohren heraus, weil einfach nicht mehr in dich hineinpasst.

Zur Illustration folgt hier eine Skizze, basierend auf zwei Public-Domain-Grafiken: Stell dir vor, [jemand](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Human.svg) bekommt jeden Tag 24 [Pfirsiche](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drupe_fruit_diagram-en.svg). Nach drei Tagen hängen sie ihm offensichtlich zu den Ohren raus:

[image: zu den Ohren raushängen]

Die Vorstufe davon (wenn man nicht bis zu den Ohren warten möchte) ist [jemandem zum Hals raushängen](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~etwas%20haengt%20einem%20zum%20Hals%20/%20Halse%20raus%20/%20heraus&suchspalte[]=rart_ou). Allerdings klingt das irgendwie auch ein bisschen "unanständiger", da man sich das zum Hals Raushängen recht bildlich als sich Übergeben, also Spucken, vorstellen kann. Beim zu den Ohren Raushängen ist klar, dass es bildlich gemeint ist, und es klingt damit sogar ein bisschen lustig. "Zu den Ohren raushängen" könnte ich mir daher in einem etwas locker formulierten Zeitungsartikel vorstellen, "zum Hals raushängen" nicht, wenn nicht tatsächlich eine extrem negative Konnotation transportiert werden soll.

Wie in der [Antwort von user unknown](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/24185/5999) beschrieben, kann "zu den Ohren raushängen" auch gezielt auf *Gehörtes* bezogen sein. Dies ist aber (zumindest hier in Südwestdeutschland) meiner Erfahrung nach nicht die einzige Interpretation. Ressourcen, die das ähnlich sehen:

- [Phraseo](http://www.phraseo.de/phrase/etwas-kommt-jemandem-zu-den-ohren-raus/): "jemand will etwas nicht mehr hören", aber auch "jemand hat etwas absolut satt"; "man mag etwas nicht mehr, da man überreichlich davon hatte" (siehe auch die dort genannten Beispiele, z.B. das mit dem Kartoffelbrei)
- [Redensarten-Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemandem%20aus%20den%20Ohren%20herauskommen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte[]=rart_ou): "etwas nicht mehr hören wollen", aber auch "übersättigt sein"
- [Hans Schemann: Deutsche Idiomatik: Wörterbuch der deutschen Redewendungen im Kontext. Walter de Gruyter, 2011](https://books.google.de/books?id=oduMIx5bOF0C&pg=PA597&lpg=PA597&dq=kommt+jm.+%28schon%29+zu+den+ohren+heraus&source=bl&ots=aR8q2h1aUR&sig=DU-Abn95JcYZxQPtnFDxv8gWnYY&hl=de&sa=X&ei=GF-UVdHRKIX5UJXHgagM&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=kommt%20jm.%20%28schon%29%20zu%20den%20ohren%20heraus&f=false): "es kommt jm. schon zu den Ohren heraus" wird als synonym zu "jm. (schon) zum Hals herauskommen" angegeben.

Und noch ein paar Praxisbeispiele, die die tatsächliche Verwendung der Redewendung aufzeigen:

- [bezogen auf Soße](http://kurier.at/politik/ausland/wahlkampf-in-israel-netanyahu-wie-sesamoel-zu-den-ohren-raus/119.266.596): '"Das ist wie mit Sesam-Soße", meinte er, "früher hab ich sie zu allem gegessen. Heute kommt sie mir zu den Ohren raus".'
- [bezogen auf Gewinnchancen](http://www.morgenpost.de/sport/fussball/article108420119/Uns-kommt-das-Potenzial-zu-den-Ohren-raus.html): '"Uns kommt das Potenzial zu den Ohren raus", umschreibt Klopp die Ausgangsposition, die er als komfortabel begreift.'
- [bezogen auf Gemüse](http://chipliste.de/dir-haengt-das-viele-gruenzeug-zu-den-ohren-raus/): "Dir hängt das viele Grünzeug zu den Ohren raus?"
- [bezogen auf eine Sorte von Büchern](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/buchmesse-2008/richard-charkin-bloggt-fuer-faz-net-belletristik-kommt-mir-zu-den-ohren-heraus-1710270.html): "Belletristik sei immer in einem Ausmaß präsent, dass sie einem zu den Ohren herauskäme."
- [bezogen auf Flaggen](https://twitter.com/janboehm/status/486441625993113600): "Mir hängen Deutschlandfahnen zu den Ohren heraus."
- [bezogen auf ein Getränk](http://www.chefkoch.de/forum/2,60,230281/Hilfe-Der-ewige-Tee-kommt-uns-zu-den-Ohren-heraus.html): "Der ewige Tee kommt uns zu den Ohren heraus!"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25457/discussion-between-robert-and-o-r-mapper).

Answer (score 6):

Im Gegensatz zu O.R. Mapper behaupte ich, dass Dir etwas zu den Ohren, sprichwörtlich, heraushängt, wenn Du es zu oft gehört hast.

Anderes hängt einem, sprichwörtlich, zum Hals raus, das war richtig.